# Opensourced File Archive system with a web ui?

Tags: files, remote, software-rec, web

I am looking for a free/opensourced archive utility for a file server. 
Basically, I am looking for an easy way to manage archives of hundreds of videos, pictures, audio files, documents, meta info, etc.

I'd like a system that I can easily attach key words, phrases, categories, etc to files, maybe a rating system, and that can easily be accessed with a WebUI or WebDAV, or something similar.

Version tracking would be a huge plus, but isn't a major requirement. What I require is the ability to easily sort through hundreds of files, play basic file types like MP3, MP4, MOV, and store key words and other useful metadata for easy indexing, organizing and searching.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a software recommendation site as every individual's needs are different and suggestion for one specific case will not benefit  the community in general

Comment: The term you're searching for is "media center" [xmbc/kodi](http://kodi.wiki/view/Skin_screenshots) is a popular choice there.

Comment: @MelBurslan I'm voting to leave this question open because Unix software is on-topic, and that includes asking for a recommendation of software for a specific purpose.

Comment: @Giles with all due respect in my earlier days here, a question of mine was voted to be closed for the very same reason. My suggestion is based on that event.

Comment: AFAIAA this is on-topic for Unix but should still be closed due to being primarily opinion based. We can offer suggestions if they're coming up with goose eggs on their end but there's no way to come up with a definitive answer as to what they'd personally find most useful. Certainly not in a way that would help others.

Comment: @MelBurslan: What use cases would that leave for the software-rec tag on this site? If you vote to close such a question, the existence of that tag should be discussed right away. If the closure of your question annoys you (I can sympathize, this happened to me in several cases as well), go against it on meta.

Comment: To answer my own question I looked at FreeNAS and OpenMediaVault. FreeNAS gave me issues with its latest version and integration with NextCloud. OpenMediaVault seems to be a little better with NextCloud, but I have yet to test it. I have to do some more testing between the two of them, but FreeNAS was basically exactly what I was looking for. Now only to get the latest version working with NextCloud and I'll be good to go.